# How to get the first and last dates/records from the employee history table

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say emp is hired on 10 Apr 15 and is transferred on 30 Apr 15 and again promoted on 10 june 15. So from this history i need the very first and last (recent record) from the emp_data. action_date are the dates mentioned above. So i need 10 Apr and 10 june as a output for my query. Action refereed as hire, transfer, etc.

This is what i am attempting-

```
select empid, action, action_dt from ps_job where
action_dt in (select min(action_dt), max(action_dt) from ps_job where empid='88888');
```

But instead it is showing me all the 3 dates from the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to modify your query to something like the following:

```
select empid, action, action_dt 
from ps_job 
where action_dt in (select min(action_dt) 
                    from ps_job 
                    where empid='88888'

                    UNION ALL

                    select max(action_dt)
                    from ps_job 
                    where empid='88888')
```

`MIN` and `MAX` should be selected as *two separate rows*, so that `IN` clause works. One way to do so is by the use of `UNION` as in the above query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e6a3/2)

Alternatively you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT empid, action, action_dt
FROM (
select empid, action, action_dt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY action_dt) AS frn,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY action_dt DESC) AS lrn
from ps_job ) t
WHERE frn = 1 OR lrn = 1
```

Note that this version is not equivalent to the first query, as there may be more than one records having the same max or min date. You have to replace `ROW_NUMBER` by `RANK` if you want *all* max, min records selected.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e6a3/3)

Comment: First one seems cool and easy for reading for the stakeholders as well. Moreover, if there are any other simple ways to execute this query, please do let me know. Thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: The above one won't work if i have another employee with the same min or max dates. Please try on the demo link as it will get the min or max date first....

Comment: @ABG Just add a `empid='88888'` predicate before `action_dt in ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the MIN and MAX functions after the first select.

If you use two different query's try something like(not tested):

```
select empid, action, MIN(action_dt) from ps_job where empid='88888')
UNION
select empid, action, MAX(action_dt) from ps_job where empid='88888');
```

Comment: I tried the above, but it returns lots of values leaving me with this error- "ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 31 Column: 10"

Comment: See the edit, is this what you are looking for? Maybe you can edit your question and add the tables.

Comment: Yes this will work with 2 separate queries, thanks, but i am looking to merger them into one :)

Comment: Add union between the query's, please mark it as 'answer'!

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed329/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ps_job ( empid, action, action_dt ) AS
          SELECT 88888, 'Join',     DATE '2015-04-10' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 88888, 'Transfer', DATE '2015-04-30' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 88888, 'Promote',  DATE '2015-06-10' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT empid,
       MIN( action ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY action_dt ) AS action,
       MIN( action_dt ) AS action_dt
FROM   ps_job
WHERE  empid = 88888
GROUP BY
       empid
UNION ALL
SELECT empid,
       MAX( action ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY action_dt ) AS action,
       MAX( action_dt ) AS action_dt
FROM   ps_job
WHERE  empid = 88888
GROUP BY
       empid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed329/1/0)**:

```
| EMPID |  ACTION |               ACTION_DT |
|-------|---------|-------------------------|
| 88888 |    Join | April, 10 2015 00:00:00 |
| 88888 | Promote |  June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT empid,
       MIN( action ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY action_dt ) AS first_action,
       MIN( action_dt ) AS first_action_dt,
       MAX( action ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY action_dt ) AS last_action,
       MAX( action_dt ) AS last_action_dt
FROM   ps_job
WHERE  empid = 88888
GROUP BY
       empid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed329/1/1)**:

```
| EMPID | FIRST_ACTION |         FIRST_ACTION_DT | LAST_ACTION |         LAST_ACTION_DT |
|-------|--------------|-------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| 88888 |         Join | April, 10 2015 00:00:00 |     Promote | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for all of u taking out your time and helping me with the queries. The above queries does work, but if i have 2 or more different employees with same action_dt then, the query does fetch the the records. For your reference, check here- [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5de5f/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, quite similar to @GiorgosBetsos. But this avoids two different `ORDER BY` within `ROW_NUMBER`, now both Windowed Aggregates can be calculated within the same step:

```
SELECT empid, action, action_dt
FROM
 (
   select empid, action, action_dt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY action_dt) AS rn,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS cnt
   from ps_job
 ) t
WHERE rn in (1, cnt)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2e6a3/5)